# Debug asssertion failed, expression: __acrt_first_block == header

Tags: c++, opencv, отладка, vector, memory

Происходит, когда пытаюсь очистить память вектора. Есть [что-то схожее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310117/debug-assertion-failed-expression-acrt-first-block-header), но я не уверен, насколько это применимо к моей проблеме, так как там был конфликт DLL и шаблона, а у меня шаблонов нет (см. ниже, оказалось, что есть, а именно `Rect`).

И `opencv` я подключаю через `.hpp`-файлы, хотя в компоновщике стоят настройки, что мне нужны `.lib`-библиотеки из `opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`, и в соседней же папке лежат `.dll`. Правда, это `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll`, `opencv_world310.dll` и `opencv_world310d.dll`.

```
cv::Size size(40, 60);
std::vector<cv::Rect> objects1, objects2;

// достаём xml с каскадом Хаара для анфаса, ищем на кадре и записываем
static_cast<cv::CascadeClassifier*>(repository->get(VisionFrontCascade))->
    detectMultiScale(*gray, objects1, 1.3, 3, 0, size);

// достаём xml с каскадом Хаара для профиля, ищем на кадре и записываем
static_cast<cv::CascadeClassifier*>(repository->get(VisionProfileCascade))->
    detectMultiScale(*gray, objects2, 1.3, 3, 0, size);

if (!objects2.empty())
{
    objects1.insert(objects1.end(), objects2.begin(), objects2.end());
    objects2.clear();
}
objects2.shrink_to_fit();    // ошибка здесь

// черчение прямоугольников вокруг найденных объектов
Concurrency::parallel_for_each(objects1.begin(), objects1.end(), [&](cv::Rect collection)
{
    auto x = collection.x, y = collection.y;
    rectangle(*frame, cv::Point(x * 2, y * 2),
        cv::Point((x + collection.width) * 2,
        (y + collection.height) * 2),
        cv::Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 255.0));    // скаляр работает в BGR
});

objects1.clear();
objects1.shrink_to_fit();    // или здесь
```

---

Оказалось, что шаблон всё-таки есть - в [cv::Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html).

Но для `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` [обязательно](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498) указывать `std::vector<cv::Rect>`.

Если убрать `shrink_to_fit()`, то ошибка происходит уже в деструкторе.

Comment: А попробуйте [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) или какой-нибудь ещё [статический анализатор кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: ну так, вы пробовали собрать с флагом /MDd ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, у меня в настройках проекта уже было указано `/MDd` для дебага и `/MD` для релиза.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre, а opencv чем (и как) собирали? суть-то проблемы в чем, в с++ память должен освобождать тот, кто её выделил (иначе будет ошибка), в вашем случае память выделяет opencv, значит и opencv должен её освободить. Обычно эта проблема решается динамической линковкой длл и ехе к одной версии CRT. Однако, если версии crt разные, то ошибка сохранится. Грязным решением проблемы является объявить эти вектора динамически, т.е. `std::vector<cv::Rect>* objects1 = new std::vector<cv::Rect>;` и не трогать их до скончания времен, это будет утечка памяти, но вы будете о ней знать).

Comment: хорошим решением является экспорт/импорт функций выделения и освобождения памяти между модулями. Но это громоздко, и не всегда осуществимо. Для освобождения памяти также можно попробовать вклиниться в чужую память посредством функций GetProcessHeap и освободить через HeapFree (но это чревато простреленной ногой). Но я думаю проблема где-то в конфигурации билдов).

Comment: @goldstar_labs, насчёт opencv не помню, кажется, я уже что-то готовое с офсайта взял.

Да, насчёт динамических векторов я рассматривал вариант, но нет, я не хочу менять одну проблему на другую.

Насчёт вклинивания в чужую память: мне кажется, что с моим опытом я как раз ногу и прострелю, повдоль причём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё-таки понял, в чём чертовщина. Когда у меня был `VS2013`, всё работало хорошо. Но потом он поломался, восстанавливаться не хотел, и я накатил проект на `VS2015`. Думая, что тот алгоритм, который хорошо работал раньше, и сейчас отлично действует, туда и не заглядывал. Когда заглянул - сабж. Так вот, сейчас я перекинул весь свой код на чистый проект, и всё работает. Спасибо всем.